# Handling RTL and LTR

Tags: jsp

I have written a code in jsp for login page.In login form i given a list of languages on selection it will reloads login page.But the problem is when i select arabic language  RTL is not happping in login page and after logged out RTL is not happening. Similar to this when i am in RTL and select English LTR is not happening. ll'r to above after logged out from english lang LTR is happening.
Please suggest me how to handle this one. Code is attached.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<%@page pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ResourceBundle"%>
<%
 String locale = null;
 String theme = null;
 String ltrRtl = "ltr";
 Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

 locale = ( String ) request.getParameter( "locale" );
 for ( int i = 0; cookies != null && i < cookies.length; i++ ) {
  Cookie c = cookies[i];
  if ( c != null && c.getName() != null && c.getName().equals( "lumina_theme" ) ) {
   theme = c.getValue();
  }
  if ( c != null && c.getName() != null && c.getName().equals( "gwtLocale" ) ) {
   if ( locale == null || "".equals( locale ) ) {
    locale = c.getValue();
   }
   ltrRtl = ( c.getValue() != null && c.getValue().equals( "ar" ) ) ? "rtl" : "ltr";
  }
 }

 if ( locale == null || "".equals( locale ) ) {
  locale = "en";
 }

 if ( theme == null || "".equals( theme ) ) {
  theme = "inception";
 }
%>

<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Properties"%>

<%
 InputStream stream = application.getResourceAsStream( "/WEB-INF/classes/LuminaSeedMessagesAndLabels_" + locale + ".properties" );
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.load( stream );
%>

<title><%=new String( props.getProperty( "Product.Name" ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" )%></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./application_gui_resources/themes/common/ltr/animations.css" />
<link
 href="application_gui_resources/themes/common/<%=ltrRtl%>/CommonLogin.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link
 href="application_gui_resources/themes/<%=theme%>/<%=ltrRtl%>/Login.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"
 href="./application_gui_resources/themes/common/ltr/icons/kivar-logo.png" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header">
  <div id="headerProductLogo"></div>
 </div>

 <%
  String code = request.getParameter( "code" );
  if ( "true".equals( request.getAttribute( "showLogInConfirm" ) ) ) {
  }
  else if ( request.getAttribute( "errorMessage" ) != null ) {
   out.print( "<div class='license-expiry-status-bar'>" + request.getAttribute( "errorMessage" ) + "</div>" );
  }
  else if ( code != null && !code.isEmpty() ) {
   out.print( "<div class='license-expiry-status-bar'>" + new String( props.getProperty( "Error.Codes." + code ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" ) + "</div>" );
  }
 %>

 <div class="row block0">
  <div class="col-3-5">
   <div class="block01 animetiondiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-3">
   <div class="block02">

    <%
     String displayValue = "display:none";
     String userName = "";
     String key = "";
     if ( "true".equals( request.getAttribute( "showLogInConfirm" ) ) ) {
      displayValue = "";
      userName = request.getParameter( "username" );
      key = request.getParameter( "password" );
     }
    %>

    <form name="login" class="bounceIn" id="Login" action="login" method="post">
     <div id="Loginmaindiv">
      <div class="headertitle"><%=new String( props.getProperty( "Login.Welcome" ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" )%></div>
      <%
       String en = "en".equals( locale ) ? "selected" : "";
       String ar = "ar".equals( locale ) ? "selected" : "";
       String fr = "fr".equals( locale ) ? "selected" : "";
       String es = "es".equals( locale ) ? "selected" : "";
      %>
      <select name='locale' class="locale"
       onchange="document.location.href = 'Login.jsp?locale=' + this.value">
       <option value="en" <%=en%>>English</option>
       <option value="ar" <%=ar%>>العربية</option>
       <option value="fr" <%=fr%>>français</option>
       <option value="es" <%=es%>>Español</option>
      </select>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="inputs">
       <input type="text" name="username"
        placeholder=<%=new String( props.getProperty( "Login.Username" ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" )%>
        autofocus value="<%=userName%>" /> <input type="password"
        name="password"
        placeholder=<%=new String( props.getProperty( "Login.Password" ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" )%>
        value="" />
       <div class="clear"></div>
       <a class="forgot-password"
        href="<%="PasswordReset.jsp?locale=" + locale%>"><%=new String( props.getProperty( "Login.ForgotPassword" ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" )%></a>
       <div class="buttondiv">
        <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"><%=new String( props.getProperty( "Login.LogIn" ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" )%></button>
       </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class='lumina-concurrent-user-login' style='<%=displayValue%>'>
   <form name="loginconfirm" id="Login" action="loginconfirm"
    method="post">
    <div id="Loginmaindiv">
     <div class="headertitle">Log In Confirmation</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
     <div class="inputs">
      <div class='lumina-concurrent-user-login-text'><%=new String( props.getProperty( "Login.ConfirmationMessage" ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" )%></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="hiddenname" value="<%=userName%>" /> <input
       type="hidden" name="hiddenkey" value="<%=key%>" />
      <div class="buttondiv">
       <button id="submit" type="submit" name='yesno' value="yes">Yes</button>
       <button id="submit" type="submit" name='yesno' value="no">No</button>
      </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"><%=new String( props.getProperty( "Login.Copyright" ).getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "UTF-8" )%></div>
</body>
</html>
```